# Declaring variables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hoping someone can help. I'm still fairly new to SQL/programming, so this might be an easy to answer quesition.

For the below script, I'm receiving an error where it's complaining that the 3 variables, @startdate, @enddate, and @result1rowcount have not been declared. I know I could move the declaration of those further down and it would work. But I want to understand the theory as to why it can't as below, as I've already declared the variables right at the start. Those declarations must get lost at some point. I'm not sure when? If someone could explain as to why it is returning the error, that would be great. I don't want suggestions on how to re-write it as such.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

Declare @count int
Declare @r int
Declare @start datetime
Declare @end datetime
Declare @startdate datetime
Declare @enddate datetime
Declare @Result1RowCount int

Set @start = DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()-1))
set @end = DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()))

Create table #tempwill
(feed int,
returnid int,
ProcessStartTime datetime,
ProcessEndTime datetime,
importcount int,
Selectedstartdate datetime,
Selectedenddate datetime)

Insert into #tempwill
Select feed, returnid, processstarttime, processendtime, importcount, selectedstartdate, selectedenddate
from Will_Database.dbo.Import
where selectedstartdate = @start 
and selectedenddate = @end

SET @COUNT = (select count(*) from #tempwill where importcount ='0')

IF @Count > 0 
     Begin
           exec @r = Bill_Database.dbo.op_Mail_2005 @profile_name = 'Testserver',
               @MailTo = 'joebloggs@hotmail.com',
               @MailBCC = '',
               @importance = 'HIGH',
               @subject = 'Warning - Numbers are not as expected',
               @body = 'Please investigate as todays numbers are not what we expected '

      End


GO

**Set @startdate = DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()-2))
set @enddate = DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()-1))**

CREATE TABLE #Results1 (ID int, Ref int, Code int, Explanation varchar(200), Timeof datetime)

INSERT #Results1 (ID, Ref, Code, Explanation, Timeof)
SELECT A.ID, B.Ref, A.Code, A.Explanation, A.Timeof
FROM Testserver.Will_database.dbo.codetime A
INNER JOIN Testserver.Bill_database.dbo.Coderegister B ON A.Code= B.Code AND A.Ref = B.Ref
WHERE  A.Timeof >= @StartDate
AND A.Timeof < @EndDate

**SELECT @Result1RowCount = @@RowCount**

**insert into Daily_Check values
( 1, 1, @Result1RowCount, @startdate, @enddate)**
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: "GO" is not a SQL command. It's a command to the processor (in most cases, SQL Server Management Studio, but also utilities like OSQL.exe and ISQL.exe) to separate long scripts into "batches". SQL Server itself will never see a 'GO' command, and wouldn't know what to do with it if it did. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because of your `GO` statement right before it.

This separates it into different batches, and declared variables are out of scope outside of the batch they were declared in.

To fix the issue, simply remove the `GO`.

Comment: or move GO to the end